# Get highest marks scored by students in each school

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `STUDENT_MARKS`:

```
SCHOOL_ID   STUDENT_ID      TTL_MARKS
--------------------------------------
8           24              78
8           25              76
9           33              88
9           34              85
9           35              88
10          41              68
10          42              68
10          43              68
```

My output should be:

```
SCHOOL_ID   STUDENT_ID      TTL_MARKS
--------------------------------------
8           24              78
9           33              88
9           35              88
10          41              68
10          42              68
10          43              68
```

I am trying with this query but not successful ::

```
SELECT 
    SCHOOL_ID, 
    STUDENT_ID, 
    MAX(TTL_MARKS) OVER(PARTITION BY SCHOOL_ID) 
FROM STUDENT_MARKS
```

How can I get the desired result in SQL Server? Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want the original rows.  So one method uses a subquery with window functions:

```
select sm.*
from (select sm.*, max(sm.ttl_marks) over (partition by school_id) as max_ttl_marks
      from student_marks sm
     ) sm
where ttl_marks = max_ttl_marks;
```

This query uses a window function to get the maximum marks for each school. The outer query then filters the rows so only the students with the maximum marks are in the result set.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I get the desired result, but I did not understand the query. How it works? Can you explain it, how the query is getting the desired result. That will be of great help. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use case for window function `RANK()`. When there are even top records, they will all be ranked first.

```
SELECT school_id, student_id, ttl_marks
FROM (
    SELECT
        school_id, 
        student_id, 
        ttl_marks,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY school_id ORDER BY ttl_marks DESC) as rn
    FROM student_marks
) s WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use window function **dense_rank()**. [Read more about window functions](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/)

```
select school_id,student_id,ttl_marks 
from 
    (select school_id,student_id,ttl_marks, 
    dense_rank() over (partition by school_id 
    order by ttl_marks desc)r from student_marks) 
where r = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregate function to get the desired result.

```
WITH A AS 
(
    SELECT *,
        MAX(ttl_marks) OVER (PARTITION BY SCHOOL_ID ORDER BY TTL_MARKS DESC) HIGH_MARK
    FROM STUDENT_MARKS

 ) SELECT 
        SCHOOL_ID, 
        STUDENT_ID, 
        MAX(ttl_marks) 
    FROM A
    GROUP BY SCHOOL_ID, STUDENT_ID, HIGH_MARK
        HAVING MAX(ttl_marks) = HIGH_MARK
```